# Want to be able to input two variables into one cell as test for data from my school

Tags: excel, vba

In our school we track students progress and teachers assign a colour code and a reason for picking this code. For example - Student A is green and there is 'no concern'. Student B is orange because of 'attendance'. We had a previous teacher generate the code and we have it working fine but the school has no asked us to add a grade to the output.

So currently it looks like

```
Student     Subject 1
Student A.  Science
        No concern - This cell in excel is green
```

There are images are what it looks like below.

From the code below we can get it to find the value against the 'Academic Progress Reason' but am after how to add the 'result' which is the next cell down.

So in the outcomes column is goes for each student for each subject they undertake
Indicator - colour picked
Reason - Attendance, etc
*new addition* Result - A, B etc

This is way beyond my basic coding skill.

Here is the code that collects the raw data and fills it into the cohort summary sheet.

```
  If (Sheets("RawData").Cells(rawRowNum, 16).Value = task) Then   'check that the data line relates to the selected task
        'check if this is a new subject for the student
        If (Sheets("RawData").Cells(rawRowNum, 22).Value) = nextTrigger Then
            subjectNum = subjectNum + 1
            Sheets("CohortSummary").Cells(1, 4 + subjectNum).Value = ("Subject " & CStr(subjectNum))
        End If

        'Find the subject for the row
        subjectName = Sheets("RawData").Cells(rawRowNum, 10).Value

        'enter traffic light data
        If Sheets("RawData").Cells(rawRowNum, 22).Value = "Progress Indicator" Then  'colour code the cell
            Select Case Sheets("RawData").Cells(rawRowNum, 20).Value
                Case "Red"
                    Sheets("OutputGrid").Cells(outputRow, subjectColumn(subjectName)).Interior.Color = red
                    Sheets("CohortSummary").Cells(outputRow, 4 + subjectNum).Interior.Color = red
                Case "Orange"
                    Sheets("OutputGrid").Cells(outputRow, subjectColumn(subjectName)).Interior.Color = orange
                    Sheets("CohortSummary").Cells(outputRow, 4 + subjectNum).Interior.Color = orange
                Case "Green"
                    Sheets("OutputGrid").Cells(outputRow, subjectColumn(subjectName)).Interior.Color = green
                    Sheets("CohortSummary").Cells(outputRow, 4 + subjectNum).Interior.Color = green
                Case Else
                    Sheets("OutputGrid").Cells(outputRow, subjectColumn(subjectName)).Interior.Color = unidentified
                    Sheets("CohortSummary").Cells(outputRow, 4 + subjectNum).Interior.Color = unidentified
                End Select
        ElseIf Sheets("RawData").Cells(rawRowNum, 22).Value = "Academic Progress Reason" Then 'enter the text into the cell
            Sheets("CohortSummary").Cells(outputRow, 4 + subjectNum).Value = (subjectName & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & Sheets("RawData").Cells(rawRowNum, 20).Value)
            Sheets("CohortSummary").Cells(outputRow, 4 + subjectNum).Value = (subjectName & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & Sheets("RawData").Cells(rawRowNum, 20).Value)
        End If
    End If



    rawRowNum = rawRowNum + 1
Loop

Sheets("OutputGrid").Select
```

[Example of raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAIi5.png)

[First row has current output, row 2 has output that I am after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOVG0.png)

Comment: Seeing a couple of example inputs with expected outputs along with a bit more of the code would IMO help. We should be able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hi QHarr and thank you for your interest in my little problem. I added more code to the original question

Comment: Use [edit] to make these changes to the question itself.

Comment: That QHarr. I've done that now. Hope this helps